# Started getting error - ACM has failed your Heroku app with Godaddy DNS

Tags: github, heroku, dns

My app has been running on Heroku hobby dynos (and DNS records on Godaddy) for over 18 months just fine. My app is connected to github and I usually use to make the deployments manually. Last week Monday April 18 2022, when I opened up heroku to make a deployment, I saw the error
Close message - Item could not be created:
Unauthorized
in the top right corner
[heroku-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sciYo.jpg) Here is my godaddy DNS [page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emb0M.jpg), [page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX8O7.jpg) and error when connecting to Github
Basically I have a root domain innovtechies.com and subdomain www. I have a forwarding defined from root to subdomain www which seems to work fine. As a consequence, SSL is failing and I cannot deploy any changes. I would greatly appreciate your suggestions and guidance. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

These two things are unrelated.

Deploying to Heroku via Github [is currently unavailable due to a security incident](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2413). You'll have to use alternate means of deploying; most typically, [`git push heroku main`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git).

Your SSL issue isn't breaking anything, but because GoDaddy is handling the no-www redirect, you're not going to be able to confirm it on Heroku. Just remove that from the Heroku SSL list; you don't need it.